# d-connectedness of d-th Suspension of Projective Spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I was going through a paper when I found this line [image]

Where the author says that d-th suspension of the Projective space is d-connected. I could not think of an argument for that. Can you please help me with this?

Also why the d-connectedness implies Whitney classes are zero? Is there a relationship between them?
Any hints will be of great help.

Comment: I’d say that the first part follows essentially from the following facts: 1) the suspension of a “reasonable” connected space is simply connected (van Kampen); 2) the “connectedness degree” of a reasonable simply connected space can be measured in homology or homotopy (Hurewicz), and 3) if $\tilde{H}_i(X)=0$ for reasonable $X$ and all $i \leq k$, then $\tilde{H}_i(\Sigma X) =0$ for all $i \leq k+1$ (Mayer-Vietoris).

Comment: @Aphelli The problem is that $\tilde{H}_i(X)=0$ for all $0 \le i \le d$ does *not* imply $d$-connectedness - the latter requires $\pi_i(X)=0$ for all $0 \le i \le d$.

Comment: @Zerox: you’re correct in general, but I think the implication holds if $X$ is simply connected, by Hurewicz’s theorem.

Comment: The second part needs more context and specifics, but a possibility could be that 1) $d$-connectedness causes the $w_i(\alpha)$ to vanish for low $i$ (because there’s no homology, see the universal coefficient theorem), and 2) the characteristic classes vanish in large degree wrt to the rank (from definitions).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your hints @Aphelli  can you explain What reasonable means there?